# Difficulty with merge sort algorithm

Tags: python, mergesort

I'm working on understanding and implementing a merge sort.  I'm running into a brick wall on this one, and can't seem to get an implementation that works.  My current implementation hits a "list index out of range" error.  Here is my code:

```
def merge_sort(list_a):
    mid = len(list_a) // 2
    print('Mid is ', mid)
    while len(list_a) > 1:
        left = list_a[:mid]
        print('Left is now ', left)
        right = list_a[mid:]
        print('Right is now ', right)
        merge_sort(left)
        merge_sort(right)
        merge(list_a, left, right)


def merge(comb_list, list_a, list_b):
    print('Starting the merge.')
    a1, b1, c1 = 0, 0, 0
    na, nb, nc = len(list_a), len(list_b), len(comb_list)
    while a1 < na and b1 < nb:
        if list_a[a1] < list_b[b1]:
            print('Adding from A')
            comb_list[c1] = list_a[a1]
            a1 += 1
        else:
            print('Adding from B')
            comb_list[c1] = list_b[b1] 
            b1 += 1

        c1 += 1

    while list_a:
        comb_list[c1] = list_a[a1]
        c1 += 1
        a1 += 1

    while list_b:
        comb_list[c1] = list_b[b1]
        c1 += 1
        b1 += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_a = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
    merge_sort(list_a)
```

Comment: `while list_a:` means `while len(list_a) != 0:`. You don't modify your `list_a` inside while block, so this cycle is interminable, variable `a1` grows and go out of list length.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made three changes to your script to get it to work. As pointed by sshdup `while list_a` will always evaluate to true as you don't remove any elements inside the loop. Therefore I have changed `while list_a:` to `len(list_a)>a1`, `while list_b:` to `len(list_b)>b1`. I also added `return merge(list_a, left, right)` to your `merge_sort` method in line with the [pseudo code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Merge_sort). After adding the `return` statement the `while` in `merge_sort` can also be replaced with an `if` statement. I have tested this on a random array of integers and it seems to work, however, as usual you should test your edge cases to make sure it works as expected.

```
def merge_sort(list_a):
    mid = len(list_a) // 2
    print('Mid is ', mid)
    if len(list_a) > 1:
        left = list_a[:mid]
        print('Left is now ', left)
        right = list_a[mid:]
        print('Right is now ', right)
        merge_sort(left)
        merge_sort(right)
        return merge(list_a, left, right)


def merge(comb_list, list_a, list_b):
    print('Starting the merge.')
    a1, b1, c1 = 0, 0, 0
    na, nb, nc = len(list_a), len(list_b), len(comb_list)
    while a1 < na and b1 < nb:
        if list_a[a1] < list_b[b1]:
            print('Adding from A')
            comb_list[c1] = list_a[a1]
            a1 += 1
        else:
            print('Adding from B')
            comb_list[c1] = list_b[b1] 
            b1 += 1

        c1 += 1

    while len(list_a)>a1:
        comb_list[c1] = list_a[a1]
        del list_a[a1]
        c1 += 1
        a1 += 1

    while len(list_b)>b1:
        comb_list[c1] = list_b[b1]        
        c1 += 1
        b1 += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_a = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
    merge_sort(list_a)
    print list_a
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the code work, you would have to make 2 adjustments:

1. Replace the while loop in the 4th line with an if-statement
2. Change the code of the while loops in the merge() function a bit

The working code:

```
def merge_sort(list_a):
    mid = len(list_a) // 2
    print('Mid is ', mid)
    #Use if statement instead
    if len(list_a) > 1:
        left = list_a[:mid]
        print('Left is now ', left)
        right = list_a[mid:]
        print('Right is now ', right)
        merge_sort(left)
        merge_sort(right)
        merge(list_a, left, right)
        #Print the result
        print(list_a)
        #Or return it directly:
        #return list_a


def merge(comb_list, list_a, list_b):
    print('Starting the merge.')
    a1, b1, c1 = 0, 0, 0
    na, nb, nc = len(list_a), len(list_b), len(comb_list)
    while a1 < na and b1 < nb:
        if list_a[a1] < list_b[b1]:
            print('Adding from A')
            comb_list[c1] = list_a[a1]
            a1 += 1
        else:
            print('Adding from B')
            comb_list[c1] = list_b[b1] 
            b1 += 1

        c1 += 1
    #Change while loop:
    while a1 < na:
        comb_list[c1] = list_a[a1]
        c1 += 1
        a1 += 1
    #Change while loop:
    while b1 < nb:
        comb_list[c1] = list_b[b1]
        c1 += 1
        b1 += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_a = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
    merge_sort(list_a)
```

You might want to return the result directly, to do that just add

```
return list_a
```

at the end of your merge_sort() function. With that approach, you could print the result directly using print(merge_sort(list_a)) in the main method.